# How to get KARATE fatures from a POSTMAN collection exported to JSON

Tags: testing, automated-tests, karate

Given a collection of API tests made with **POSTMAN** , that are exportable to `json` as *postman_collection* in some format ( v1 or v2 )
[image]

Is it possible to integrate (import) and execute these test in [**KARATE**](https://github.com/intuit/karate) projects ?

I was wondering if there are already open source tools or projects that have faced this effort or if there are particular reasons why obtaining `karate features` from the `json` exported by POSTMAN should be impossible or not recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some work done for this - would be great if you can test and improve via a PR if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1008

Here's an example of using the Java API: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/formats/postman/ConvertUtilsTest.java

This should be available in 0.9.5 / 0.9.6.RC3

Comment: When I click on the example it gives me a 404

Comment: I am wondering if there's a tool or cli commands that can move postman collections to karate scenario's yet ? If not, what could be a recommended way to do the same ?

Comment: @CuriousLearner recommended way is you contribute code or influence someone you know to do so ^_^